# QueryOver with constraint on one of the elements which is a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, join, queryover

I'm trying to do the following:

```
   var query = session.QueryOver<BaseEntity>()
                    .JoinAlias(x => x.FirstChild, () => FirstChildAlias)
                    .JoinAlias(x => x.SecondChild, () => SecondChildAlias)
                    .JoinAlias(() => SecondChildAlias.ListOfElementsChild, () => ListOfElementsChildAlias)
                    .Where(() => FirstChild.Text == "value 1")
                    .And(() => ListOfElementsChildAlias.Text =="value2");
```

How can I make constraints on the inner child which is of type List!?
how can I get all BaseEntity elements that has a list with at least one child in the list having it's Text value equal to "value2"?

Comment: Not sure, but you may give a try to .WithSubquery.WhereExists This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/7742453/1236044

Comment: @jbl is right.  An `exists` subquery is exactly what you need.  See [one of my other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7376077/221708) for a good example of how to do this.

Comment: Actually I've tried Exists and didn't work! it retrieved non-matching data with the wanted results!
I've used Criteria to solve this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an equivalent solution that worked out for me:

```
                var query = session.CreateCriteria<BaseEntity>("BaseEntity")
                                   .CreateCriteria("BaseEntity.FirstChild", "FirstChild")
                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("FirstChild.Text", firstChildTextValue))
                                   .CreateCriteria("BaseEntity.SecondChild", "SecondChild")
                                   .CreateCriteria("SecondChild.ListOfElementsChild", "ListOfElementsChild")
                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ListOfElementsChild.Text", listOfElementsChildTextValue))
                                    .List<BaseEntity>();
```